# How does one use Apple News API to automatically publish content?

Tags: node.js, rest, feed, apple-news

We're using the [Apple News REST API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_news/apple_news_api) to automatically "publish" articles from our custom CMS into Apple News.

So far, we've been using the `Create an Article` API to generate an Apple News compatible article to publish. However, I was unable to find an API request that actually publishes it. Just creating the article puts it into our "Drafts" section of our Apple News Publisher account, which we then have to manually publish.

This is very cumbersome and manual. Is there some sort of API available for moving articles from Drafts into Published? We've reached out to Apple's Developer Forum to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Apple lets you publish articles immediately by setting "isPreview" to false in your request metadata. See details there: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_news/create_article_metadata_fields

**Note:** Your channel needs to be approved for this to work.